# Get the Azure App Service Environment outbound IP

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm deploying an App Service Environment and I need to get its outbound IP. Once deployed I can see the IP in the resource manager and I should be able to get the info using the following CmdLet:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName asepoc-base -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/capacities -ResourceName asepocxxxx/virtualip -ApiVersion 2015-08-01
```

But this command does not return anything, althought the full json object can be viewed using fiddler in the Http response.

I'm I missing something ? Is there another way (maybe directly in the ARM template using reference()) to get the IP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier way:

```
(Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name yyy).OutboundIpAddresses
```

Your way:

```
(Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName xxx-ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion yyy -ResourceName zzz).Properties.OutboundIpAddresses
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Although it's somewhat weird that we are not able to retrieve any IP from the ASE directly...